# Angular and NodeJS GET request url with params returns only response object no component HTML

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular2-routing

I have a URL like for example **'localhost:3000/verify/a5d5sd'**, that I have sent to a user's email, upon clicking this link, I am using the param (a5d5sd) in the link for checking some stuff in the server and database(MongoDB) and returning a response with an object, now when the link is clicked or opened on a new tab, I only see the response from the server but not with the HTML from my Angular 2 component.

In my Angular 2 route config module, I did config a route like

```
  {
    path: 'verify/:id',
    component: MyComponent
  },
```

And on ngOnInit of this component, I am calling a service method that makes a GET http request with a URL like **verify/:id** the **param(:id)** I get it using the ActivatedRoute from the @angular/router so that I can make the request.

To handle this I was advised to have the following code for my express to use:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/dist')));

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/dist/index.html');
})
```

Have even tried with:

```
app.all('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/dist/index.html');
})
```

This code works for direct navigation(pasting URLon the search bar) and refreshes for only **POST** and **PUT** requests but not working with **GET** requestS that expects a response from the server side, when I directly visit a URL or refresh the page, the DOM is written with the server response but with not HTML, any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After define all routes, add the route for the index.html file

```
// Set your routes here
app.use('/api', api);

// Catch all other routes and return the index file
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'path/to/index.html')); //path from the root dir
});
```

This was work for me. 
Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that it's the order of the route that is the issue?

Comment: yes. I think so. If you add the * thing above the other route definition, node will only hit on * route.

Comment: Okay I cannot really test the solution now, but did you move the * above, does it not work in your case

Comment: No of cause not. It is because nodejs find the fitted router link from top to bottom. * mean any, so it match any thing that is not match to the above routes. so the router definition that is below *, will never hit.

Comment: Okay thank you, will mark as correct after testing, I appreciate it.

Comment: Hppy to help u.